# hide the checkbox based on value in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the checkboxes with values leads,contacts and Blank and I want to hide the checkbox and lable with values Blank and Contacts I have tried as.but not able to hide the option.

```js
 $('#relatedto input').val('Blank').hide();
  $('#relatedto input').val('Contacts').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedto'>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Leads" id="ms-opt-1" value="Leads">Leads</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Contacts" id="ms-opt-1" value="Contacts">Contacts</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Blank" id="ms-opt-1" value="Blank">Blank</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors have been adjusted, and you have to get the parent to hide both the label and the input inside it.

```js
$('#relatedto input[value="Blank"]').parent().hide();
$('#relatedto input[value="Contacts"]').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedto'>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Leads" id="ms-opt-1" value="Leads">Leads</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Contacts" id="ms-opt-1" value="Contacts">Contacts</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Blank" id="ms-opt-1" value="Blank">Blank</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried hiding input but label is not hidden so this is making you trouble. Please try this:

```js
 $('#leads').hide();
  $('#contacts').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedto'>

<label id='leads' for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Leads" id="ms-opt-1" value="Leads">Leads</label>

<label id='contacts' for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Contacts" id="ms-opt-1" value="Contacts">Contacts</label>

<label id='blank' for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Blank" id="ms-opt-1" value="Blank">Blank</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a direct selector or use the jQuery `.filter()` method as shown below, and the `.closest()` method to step back to the `label` element.

```js
$('#relatedto input').filter(function() {
    return ['Blank','Contacts'].includes( this.value.trim() ) 
})
.closest('label').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedto'>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Leads" id="ms-opt-1" value="Leads">Leads</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Contacts" id="ms-opt-1" value="Contacts">Contacts</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Blank" id="ms-opt-1" value="Blank">Blank</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector `[attr=]` to select the element and use `parent()` get the label and hide() it.

```js
$("#relatedto input[value='Blank']").parent().hide();
$("#relatedto input[value='Contacts']").parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='relatedto'>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Leads" id="ms-opt-1" value="Leads">Leads</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Contacts" id="ms-opt-1" value="Contacts">Contacts</label>
<label for="ms-opt-1"><input type="checkbox" title="Blank" id="ms-opt-1" value="Blank">Blank</label>
</div>
```